# Reparameterize a path $C^1$ to a path $C^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\large \alpha:I\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a path of class $\large C^1$

We can reparameterize  $\large \alpha$  such that $\large \beta= \alpha\circ h \in\large C^\infty$ ? Where $\large h:J\longrightarrow I$

$I,J:$ Intervals

---

For example reparameterize the trace of the absolute value$$\large \alpha(t)=(t,|t|)$$ $$\large h(s)=s\cdot \theta(s)$$ then

$$\large \beta(s)=(\alpha \circ h)(s)=(s\cdot \theta(s), |s|\cdot \theta(s)) \in C^{\infty}$$ where

$$\large\theta(s)= e^{-1 /s^2},\theta(0)=0$$

Note that $\large \alpha(t)=(t,|t|)$ is only continuous.

We can generalize this property to surfaces ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: First, your $\alpha$ failed to be differentiable at precisely one point. You don't know that a general $C^1$ function fails to be smooth only at a single point. But your reparametrization is not regular, even as it stands, since it has vanishing velocity at $0$. In differential geometry, parametrizations that are not regular (i.e., not immersions) are not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know where you are heading with the example below the horizontal line. My understanding of a $C^1$ curve is that it's a $C^1$ map *with nonvanishing derivative* from an interval into some manifold.  For $C^\infty$ curves, it's the same but we also require the map to be $C^\infty$.

A $C^1$ curve cannot in general be made into a $C^\infty$ curve by reparametrization. For example, take $\gamma(t)=(t,t|t|)$ which is a $C^1$ curve in $\mathbb R^2$. Suppose that $\lambda = (x(t),y(t))$ is a $C^\infty$ curve with the same image. Say, $\lambda(t_0)=(0,0)$. The geometry of $\gamma$ dictates $y(t)=o(x(t))$ as $t\to t_0$, which implies $y'(t_0)=0$. Hence $x'(t_0)\ne 0$. By the inverse function theorem, we can invert $x(t)$ locally: $t=f(x)$ where $f$ is $C^\infty$ smooth. Then $y(f(x))=x|x|$ must be $C^\infty$ smooth as a composition, which is false: it's not even $C^2$.